# Sincronização de Thread em Java (sincronizar coleções)

Tags: java, thread

Tenho definido uma `Thread` em Java na qual pretendo simular aviões chegando e partindo do aeroporto, a classe `Aviao` contém apenas número e 10 passageiros

```
public class Aviao  {
    //numero de Aviao
    private int numeroAviao;
    //contém uma lista de passageiros
    private List<Passageiro> passageiros;

   public Aviao(int numero, int tamanho) {
            this.numeroAviao = numero;
            this.passageiros = new ArrayList<>(tamanho);
    }

    @Override
    public void adicionaPassageiro(Passageiro p) {
            this.passageiros.add(p);
    }
}
```

A classe `Aeroporto`:

```
public class Aeroporto {
    private List<Passageiro> passageirosNoAeroporto;
    private List<Aviao> avioes;
    private Map<Aviao, ThreadAviao> threadAviao;
    private final Object mutex;
    private boolean comecou;
    private final Relogio relogio;

public Aeroporto(int qtAviao) {
        this.mutex = new Object();
        this.comecou = false;
        this.passageirosNoAeroporto = new ArrayList<>();
        this.avioes = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        this.relogio = new Relogio();
        this.threadAviao = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < qtAviao; j++) {
            Aviao aviao = new Aviao(j + 1, 10);
            this.threadAviao.put(aviao, new ThreadAviao(this, aviao));
     }
}
```

Método adicionar avião no aeroporto:

```
public synchronized void AviaoChegou(Aviao aviao) throws InterruptedException {
        //adicionar aviao no aeroporto
        this.avioes.add(aviao);
        //usar uma lista sincronizada
        List list = Collections.synchronizedList(avioes);
        synchronized (list) {
            //iterar lista de avioes
            Iterator i = list.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                aviao = (Aviao) i.next();
                // iterar a lista de passageiros
                Iterator<Passageiro> it = aviao.getPassageiros().iterator();
                  while (it.hasNext()) {
                     Passageiro p = it.next();
                     //adicionar os pasageiros no aeroporto
                     passageirosNoAeroporto.add(p);
                     //remove os passageiros do aviao
                     it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Método para avião partir quando estiver vazio

```
 public synchronized void AviaoPartiu(Aviao aviao) {
      //usar uma lista sincronizada
            List<Aviao> lista = Collections.synchronizedList(avioes);
            synchronized (lista) {
              //iterar a lista de avioes
                Iterator<aviao> i = lista.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    aviao = (Aviao) i.next();
                   //remove o aviao do aeroporto -> e da thread Aviao e Dá erro
                   //(Exception in thread 
                   //"Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException)
                    this.avioes.remove(aviao); //usar isto ou não?
                   //remove o aviao do aeroporto -> e não da thread Aviao?
                   i.remove();//usar isto o aviao 
                  //faz a simulação outra vez até morrer
                }
            }
        }
```

e depois tenho a classe `ThreadAviao`

```
public class ThreadAviao extends Thread {

        private final Aviao aviao;
        private final Aeroporto aeroporto;

        public ThreadAviao(Aeroporto aeroporto, Aviao aviao) {
            this.aviao = aviao;
            this.aeroporto = aeroporto;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (mutex) {
                    while (!comecou) {
                        mutex.wait();
                    }
                List<Aviao> lista = new ArrayList<>();
                //adiciona o aviao a lista
                lista.add(aviao);
                //ordena os avioes
                Collections.sort(lista);
                //escolhe um aviao 
                for (Aviao av : lista) {
                    //inicia a etapa
                    etapaAviao.executar(aeroporto, av);
                }
               }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Não faz nada.
            }
        }
    }
```

Minha dúvida é que quando tenho 2 aviões criado em vez de cada um faz o seu processo, e quando um partir e é removido do da lista de aviões no aeroporto dá erro tal como mostra a imagem abaixo

[image]

e o meu objetivo é tentar sincronizar a `Thread` para que possa atingir o objetivo tal como mostra na figura em baixo?

[image]

> acho que o problema mesmo é que não está excluindo o avião do
>   aeroporto quando partiu com destino a outro país

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: o método AviaoPartiu vc está removendo todos os aviões?

Comment: @Skywalker, apenas estou removendo o aviao que chegou, alterei o metodo aviao partiu, o aviao que vai partir será igual ao aviao iterado da lista e apagado atraves  da operação  `this.avioes.remove(aviao); ` e depois a thread do outro aviao executa mas só que dá erro depois

Comment: @Skywalker, se no método aviaoPartiu eu estiver removendo todos os aviões, acho que a outra `thread` não iria executar como mostra na figura 1

Comment: Assim, não tinha visto aquele if de comparação,  experimente dar  `break;` após remover. Isso deve resolver.

Comment: Não sei se é necessário isso `i.remove();`

Comment: @Skywalker,  experimentei dar `break;` após remover o aviao em `this.avioes.remove(aviao);` e não deu erro mas não resolveu e continuou a executar  a etapa do mesmo aviao que acabou de partir

Comment: Ai ja é problema da lógica. Logo vo da mais uma analisada no seu código.

Comment: @Skywalker, obrigado

Comment: @Skywalker, acho que consegui resolver o problema do erro e na verdade em vez de usar o `this.avioes.remove(aviao);` o melhor mesmo é usar `i.remove();` quando estámos usar o iterador para eliminar um objeto numa lista,e não tinha que fazer nenhuma condição `if`, era necessario fazer `aviao = (Aviao) i.next();` e depois na execução da etapa e criar um `contador` para controla a etapa de cada thread que será executada apenas  vez e deu certo como mostra na figura em cima, apenas falta ordenar e visto que resolve a minha dúvida a solução está foi edita no codigo que já tinha sido colocado antes.

Comment: Olá Renata, bem vinda ao [pt.so]. Vi que resolveu o seu problema, legal! Só que a solução deveria estar como resposta, pois aqui funcionamos um pouco diferentes dos fóruns. Poderia separar a pergunta da resposta em publicações diferentes? Aproveite e faça um [tour] para conhecer um pouco melhor o funcionamento da nossa comunidade.

Comment: @Math, obrigada pela orientação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

já consegui colocar a funcionar como esperado, eis a solução

a classe `Aviao` contém apenas número e 10 passageiros

```
public class Aviao implements Comparable<Aviao>  {
    //numero de Aviao
    private int numeroAviao;
    //contém uma lista de passageiros
    private List<Passageiro> passageiros;

   public Aviao(int numero, int tamanho) {
            this.numeroAviao = numero;
            this.passageiros = new ArrayList<>(tamanho);
    }

    public void adicionaPassageiro(Passageiro p) {
            this.passageiros.add(p);
    }

    public List<Passageiro> getPassageiros() {
            return this.passageiros;
    }

   public int getNumeroAviao() {
           return this.numeroAviao;
    }

   public int compareTo(Aviao novoAviao) {
            return this.numeroAviao - novoAviao.getNumeroAviao();
    }
}
```

A classe `Aeroporto`:

```
public class Aeroporto {
    private List<Passageiro> passageirosNoAeroporto;
    private List<Aviao> avioes;
    private Map<Aviao, ThreadAviao> threadAviao;
    private final Object mutex;
    private boolean comecou;
    private final Relogio relogio;

public Aeroporto(int qtAviao) {
        this.mutex = new Object();
        this.comecou = false;
        this.passageirosNoAeroporto = new ArrayList<>();
        this.avioes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.relogio = new Relogio();
        this.threadAviao = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < qtAviao; j++) {
            Aviao aviao = new Aviao(j + 1, 10);
            this.threadAviao.put(aviao, new ThreadAviao(this, aviao));
     }
}
```

Método adicionar avião no aeroporto:

```
public synchronized void AviaoChegou(Aviao aviao) throws InterruptedException {
        //adicionar aviao no aeroporto
        this.avioes.add(aviao);
        //usar uma lista sincronizada
        List<Aviao> lista = Collections.synchronizedList(avioes);
        synchronized (lista) {
            //iterar lista de avioes
            Iterator<Aviao> i = lista.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                  // o aviao que chegou é igual ao aviao iterado
                  aviao = (Aviao) i.next();
                // iterar a lista de passageiros
                Iterator<Passageiro> it = aviao.getPassageiros().iterator();
                  while (it.hasNext()) {
                     Passageiro p = it.next();
                     //adicionar os pasageiros no aeroporto
                     passageirosNoAeroporto.add(p);
                     //remove os passageiros do aviao
                     it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

Método para avião partir quando estiver vazio

```
 public synchronized void AviaoPartiu(Aviao aviao) {
      //usar uma lista sincronizada
            List<Aviao> lista = Collections.synchronizedList(avioes);
            synchronized (lista) {
              //iterar a lista de avioes
                Iterator<aviao> i = lista.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                  //aviao que vai partir é igual ao aviao iterado
                  aviao = (Aviao) i.next();
                   //remove o aviao do aeroporto
                   i.remove();
            }
          }
        }
```

e depois tenho a classe `ThreadAviao`

```
    public class ThreadAviao extends Thread {

            private final Aviao aviao;
            private final Aeroporto aeroporto;

            public ThreadAviao(Aeroporto aeroporto, Aviao aviao) {
                this.aviao = aviao;
                this.aeroporto = aeroporto;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (mutex) {
                        while (!comecou) {
                            mutex.wait();
                        }
                   //usar uma lista sincronizada
                    List<Aviao> lista = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
                    //adiciona o aviao a lista
                    lista.add(this.aviao);
                    //escolhe um aviao 
                    synchronized (lista) {
                    for (Aviao novoAviao : lista) {
                    System.out.println(" Aviao " + novoAviao.numeroAviao());
                      //inicia a etapa
                      etapaAviao.executar(this.aeroporto, novoAviao);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Não faz nada.
                }
            }
        }
```

método que executa a etapa do aviao

```
public void executar(Aeroporto aeroporto, Aviao aviao) {
         //contador
         int contador = 0;
        //por enquanto a cada aviao executar uma 
        //etapa sai de executa a etapa de outro aviao
        while (contador != 1) {
            aeroporto.AviaoChegou(aviao);
            //aguardar um tempo
            aeroporto.getRelogio().esperar();
            //aviao partiu
            aeroporto.AviaoPartiu(aviao);
            //incrementa contador
            contador++;
        }
    }
```

eis a figura da simulação
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]